# How do you calculate the final metrics for K-cross validation from confusion matrix?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation

[image: Here is the question]

The answer for which is option is E but I am unable to figure how did they calculate it. Can someone do it step by step?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate k-fold cv accuracies, there are several options but the two you are after are to:

1. Calculate the average fold accuracy (6/10+10/10+8/11)/3. = 0.776
2. Calculate the overall accuracy across folds (6+7+6+3+2)/(10+10+11) = 0.7742

Essentially both are saying "how many samples did we get correct out of the total number of samples", but just in a per-fold, or per-sample mindset.

Just as a point of interest, if you do the first method you will also usually calculate the standard deviation of the accuracies too.